# UIAccelerometer called from subview not working

Tags: ipad, uiview, delegates, uiviewcontroller, uiaccelerometer

I have an "interesting" issue with the UIAccelerometer in an app for the iPad.

In my UIViewController I have a method that activates the Accelerometer. This is how it looks like:

```
-(void)startAcc{

UIAccelerometer *gForce = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
gForce.delegate = self;
gForce.updateInterval = kUpdateInterval;
}
```

In my viewWillAppear I call this method to activate the Accelerometer, and it works just fine. I recieve accelerations and use it to move a view on screen.

On user input I then load another view (UIView) that need to use the accelerometer. So I stop the accelerometer in my UIViewController with this code:

```
[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = nil;
```

I then load the UIView and activates the accelerometer there in the same way. All works just fine.

My issue begins when I want to close the UIView and start the accelerometer in the UIViewController again. I stop it in the UIView and call the startAcc method in my UIViewController from the UIView. The method executes, but I receive no accelerations :-(

Same method, but different results.

Can anyone guide me to what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi everybody. Solved it. By putting  [self resignFirstResponder];  after I call the startAcc method from the subview it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. By putting [self resignFirstResponder]; after I call the startAcc method from the subview it works.